# I am looking for the source and/or proper definition for the int() function

Tags: c++

I am looking for the source and/or proper definition for the int() function.
I have searched through the source in Arduino.app, without much success.

The reference gives a terse explanation

```
int(x)
 x: a value of any type 
 Converts a value to the int data type
```

Passing 1, '1' or 49 returns the int 1. I haven't tested other types.

This seems to be an Arduino specific function - it doesn't seem to be in any c/c++ library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int(x)` is not a function but **another way to perform an explicit cast** of `x` to an `int`. It is part of the C++ language itself, that is why you could not find it in a library.

This is not Arduino-specific.

In C and C++ you can cast a value to an int by doing this:

```
int y = (int) x;
```

**C++** has extended this notation by allowing to do it this way, which is equivalent:

```
int y = int(x);
```

You can find this [in more details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) in C++ language reference.

Comment: to clear things i think add `long x;` above `int y = int(x);` in my opinion this would be better?

Comment: Thanks. I could not find this in any of my (admittedly old) c++ books, or in Xcode documentation.